# document.onclick vs window.onclick

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any difference between

```
document.onclick
```

and

```
window.onclick
```

event?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The JavaScript Window object is the highest level JavaScript object which corresponds to the web browser window.

The document object is the container for all HTML HEAD and BODY objects associated within the HTML tags of an HTML document. This could correspond to the top-most window, or an iframe within the window.

**Update**

After a quick test there really is no difference between the two. However, as others have said, window.onclick did not work when tested in IE8. So apparently the bottom line is that `document.onclick` is the preferred choice.

Comment: Since it hasn't been mentioned, `window.onclick` is supported in IE9+.

Comment: This is odd, but I stumbled across this after failing to get window.onclick to work. Out of curiosity, I tried document.onclick and everything worked fine. This is tested on the latest version of Google Chrome as of Feb 14, 2018. Was window.onclick deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

I've heard of some versions of IE not supporting window.onclick

Comment: I tested and found that window.onclick does not work in IE8. I did not test it in other version of IE. However window.onclick works in FireFox.

Comment: If it doesn't work in IE8 I'd put money that it doesn't work in IE at all

Answer (score 3):

The w3c describes the document as: "The Document interface represents the entire HTML or XML document. Conceptually, it is the root of the document tree, and provides the primary access to the document's data." (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#i-Document)

and window as: "...defines the Window object, which provides the global namespace for web scripting languages, access to other documents in a compound document by reference, navigation to other locations, and timers. The Window object is a long-standing de facto standard for HTML user agents. However, it should not be assumed based on this or the name "Window" that it is limited to HTML or to visual user agents." (http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/)

So to answer your question, depending on the browser there might not be any issue. But some browser vendors might implement them differently.

Answer (score 2):

If there are any differences at all, I am not aware of any. I believe in the end the `document` references the `window`.

Comment: you might mean "`document` mouse events reference the `window` mouse events", but the `document` element most certainly does not reference `window`. That could be very misleading to someone that doesn't understand the difference between the two.