# Setting div height to document height using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to set the height of the sidebar divs to the height of the document. For some reason it doesnt work

```
var l=$(document).height(); 
$("#sidebar,#sidebar_right").height(l);
```

Firebug shows that the height for the document is always larger than the one for the sidebars.. Does anyone know why it isnt working ? ( If i refresh the page 5,6 times it gets closer , but never the exact height )

Comment: Are the sidebars contained in any elements that grow when the sidebars grow? Or are the sidebars positioned absolutely? Maybe you'd rather want to achieve this filling effect with CSS.

Comment: Looks like your code works, we need to see the html and css in context to find the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/PyuzB/

Comment: Didnt work, i used a timer that refreshed it 4 times, it used an approximate but works for the time being.

Comment: Where and when do you execute this code? Within `document.ready`? Or at the bottom of the page?

Comment: bottom of the page with documen.ready

Comment: Could you post more of your html and CSS so I can see what your trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

You can use this,

```
function sideHeight() {
  var wH = $(window).height();

  $('#sidebar, #sidebar_right').css({
      height: wH
  });
}

sideHeight();
```

It will find the height of the the page and then set it for the div through `.css`

You can also set like half of the body height like so, `var wH = $(window).height()/2;`

or `var wH = $(window).height() - 300;`

If you want to use document instead of window then more power to you.

```
function sideHeight() {
  var wH = $(document).height();

  $('#sidebar, #sidebar_right').css({
      height: wH
  });
}

sideHeight();
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/T5qXF/)

[window vs document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384127/document-onclick-vs-window-onclick)